# Qual maneira correta de salvar imagens em um servidor?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Sei que a resposta para essa pergunta não é exata, mas estou perguntando devido a alertas que recebi da hospedagem de um cliente (media temple - DV Developer)

O sistema que desenvolvi salva as imagens da seguinte forma:

```
/uploads/nome-do-modulo/ano/mes/dai/nome-imagem-encriptado.ext
```

A media temple me enviou uma alerta dizendo que **eu tenho muitas imagens em uma única pasta**.

Realmente

---

#### My host config

- Ubuntu 12.04 server
- Apache 2.4.x
- PHP 5.5.x

---

*Sorry for my english.*

If you need more informations, tell me.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link aqui [Ḿicrosoft](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525), acho que vai ser bem útil pra você ter mais informações de como vai armazenar as imagens. Um resumo você pode encontrar aqui [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613898/storing-images-in-sql-server). Geralmente o que eu costumo fazer é guardar as imagens no filesystem e mantenho uma referencia a elas no banco.

Answer (score 5):

Eu utilizo uma técnica que aprendi com a estrutura de uma plataforma EC chamada PrestaShop.

É um pouco complicado explicar, então vou mostrar um exemplo. Até porque eu desconheço se existe um termo apropriado para definir essa técnica.

Para imagens de um produto, cujo ID é 150, as imagens ficariam dentro da seguinte estrutura

```
/images/products/1/5/0/ddshdfhiioiuo.jpg
/images/products/1/5/0/eyfghioiuor.jpg
/images/products/1/5/0/aytdklkkoiuo.jpg
```

Para o nome das imagens, utilizo um script que gera strings únicas, com finalidade de evitar conflito com arquivos existentes.
Mas isso é algo pessoal, você pode optar por outros métodos.
O mais importante aqui é a estrutura onde as imagens são armazenadas.

Se eu quero gerar imagens de dimensões diferentes, exemplo 150px, 750px, 350px, ficaria assim:

Pegando com exemplo a primeira imagem da lista acima:

```
/images/products/1/5/0/ddshdfhiioiuo.jpg (essa é a original, sem compressão, filtros, etc)
/images/products/1/5/0/ddshdfhiioiuo_150.jpg (essa é a de 150 px)
/images/products/1/5/0/ddshdfhiioiuo_750.jpg (essa é a de 750 px)
/images/products/1/5/0/ddshdfhiioiuo_350.jpg (essa é a de 350 px)
```

O intuito em manter a original é poder gerar outras imagens com dimensões diferentes se necessário.

Por quê o seu host pediu para que reduza a quantidade de imagens numa só pasta? 
Obviamente porque fica muito pesado. 
Imagine um ecommerce pequeno de 50 mil produtos, sendo que cada um tem 5 imagens com 3 ou 4 versões de cada imagem. Quando entra nessa pasta pelo FTP é um terror. Um pesadelo, principalmente para o servidor do host.

**Vamos aprender algo interessante e muito simples com PHP**

Como gerar um diretório images/products/1/5/0 a partir do número 150?

```
/**
Aqui é definido a base do diretório.
Evite usar paths relativos. Utilize sempre paths absolutos.
*/
$path = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images/products' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

/**
O id do produto
*/
$item_id = 150;

/**
Cada caracter será convertido em valores de índices num array
*/
$arr = str_split( $item_id );

/**
Converte o array numa string onde cada valor é separado por DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

Exemplo, 150 ficará como 1/5/0 ou 1\5\0
*/
$folder = implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $arr );

/**
Concatena a base com o folder, formando o path absoluto final
*/
$path .= $folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

/**
Descarta os objetos que não serão mais usados. 
Isso é útil somente para micro otimizações.
*/
unset( $arr, $folder );

/**
Verifica se o path já não existe. Caso não existir, prossegue a operação
*/
if( !file_exists( $path ) )
{

    /**
    A função mkdir faz a mágica com ajuda do terceiro parâmetro.
    Quando o terceiro parâmetro receber (bool)TRUE, indica que os subfolders são criados recursivamente. Portanto, não precisa se preocupar em fazer laços de repetição para criar os subfolders.
    */
    if( !mkdir( $path, 0777, true ) )
    {
        /**
        * Se cair aqui, houve algum erro. É aconselhável retornar códigos de erro
        O código abaixo é meramente didático, para exemplo.
        */
         $error_code = 303;
    }
}
```

Comment: Daniel, agradeço a resposta. Conheço este método para salvar imagens e gerar somente sob demanda, mas neste cliente não pude aplicar quando desenvolvi, e agora creio que migrar seria complicado. No mais, creio que, ainda que haja somente 1 imagem para cada produto/post, ainda sim em 1 ou 2 anos dependendo da demanda, a pasta ainda sim ficará cheia e pesada. Ou não?

Comment: A pasta pode ter mais de 1 bilhão de imagens, sem problemas. O problema é ter "1 bilhão" de arquivos numa única pasta. A lógica dessa estrutura que lhe apresentei é reduzir a quantidade em subfolders seccionados. Assim não fica pesado para listagens, por exemplo. O problema atual que ocorre contigo, o qual o seu host reclamou é o exceço de arquivos numa única pasta, conforme já mencionei acima.

Comment: Outro ponto é, não requer migração alguma.. Talvez vc tenha entendido errado quando mencionei PrestaShop. Não disse  que deve migrar para o PRestaShop ou qualquer outra plataforma.. Basta aplicar a implementação diretamente na sua aplicação atual.  Mais um detalhe. A estrutura que passei acima é baseada no PrestaShop, porém, eu não li os códigos do PS para ver como é feito. Eu criei o meu próprio que é esse aí, o qual apresenta o mesmo resultado.

Comment: É.. vou dar uma pesquisada neste método. No meu caso ainda sim ficou bem dividido: módulo/ano/mes/dia/nome-da-imagem, porém ainda sim houve essa reclamação do servidor. No mais, te agradeço.

Comment: essa técnica também é bacana. Então qual o motivo do host reclamar? Talvez o tamanho dos arquivos?

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente eu prefiro converter as imagens em uma string base64 e salvar no banco de dados com o nome e source em uma tabela imagens.

Comment: não é bem isso... o problema é o excesso de arquivos numa única pasta.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta meu amigo, mas não é bem isso.