# Estruturar no banco os caminhos para as imagens e videos do meu produto?

Tags: sql, modelo-relacional

Como posso estruturar no banco de dados os caminhos para as imagens e videos do meu produto?

Abaixo a SQL de criação da tabela produto:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  quantity INT NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(1000),
  price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
  status INT NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME
);
```

Serão salvos os caminhos para:

- Fotos do produto
- Thumbnail (foto pequena descritiva do produto)
- Videos do produto

E como diferencio cada caminho (caso o usuário queira determinado foto ou todas as fotos)?

Comment: Ora ai está uma boa pergunta...

Comment: essa resposta pode ser útil: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73194/qual-maneira-correta-de-salvar-imagens-em-um-servidor/73201#73201

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu criaria duas tabelas para guardar essa informação. Porque pode ser possível que uma foto se aplique a mais que um produto. Caso isso nunca aconteça podes simplificar o modelo, mas eu faria assim:

Uma tabela genérica para guardar informação da imagem ou video

```
create table Media 
(
     id   
     type        -- Tipo de media (imagem, thumbnail, video, word document, ...)
     filepath
     description -- meta data, para permitir busca por imagem por exemplo...
)
```

Outra tabela para gerir as relações Produto-Media

```
create table ProductsMedia
(
   productID
   mediaID
)
```

Desta forma seria fácil para você filtrar o tipo de conteúdo dependendo da escolha do utilizador. Caso pretende ver todo o tipo de conteúdo associado a um produto nenhum filtro seria necessário. Caso apenas queira ver imagens então basta filtrar por esse conteúdo em particular, fazendo por exemplo:

```
select p.name,
       p.description,
       pprice,
       m.id
from products p
left join ProductsMedia pm
  on pm.productID = p.id
left join Media m
  on m.id = pm.mediaID
where m.type = 'foto'            -- apenas um exemplo
  and m.metadata like %gato%-- imagens em que apareça um gato
```

Comment: Boa resposta +1